# complete DVR which has the same residue field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ and $R'$ be a DVR, both are complete （ with respect to its maximal ideal $M$）, and $R$ and $R'$ are both have the same uniformizer $π$.
We assume $R$ and $R'$ has the same residue （as a set）.

Then, $R$ and $R'$ is the same ring （as a set）?

Comment: This looks a lot like [this other question you posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4109326/29335). Could you merge whatever changes you have here into that one and delete this one please?

Comment: I added completeness of $R$ and $R'$. Without completeness, there were easy counter example, so I opened new question.

Comment: ok, if this is so, then pleases delete that question, or self-answer it, and then clearly distinguish the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "as a set" and I will assume the statement you are interested in is the following:

> **Lemma** Let $(R, \pi)$ and $(S,\varpi)$ be two complete DVR with their respective uniformizer. Assume that there exists a homomorphism
> $$ f:R\to S$$
> such that
>
> 1. $f(\pi)=\varpi$
> 2. $f:R/\pi\to S/\varpi$ is an isomorphism.
>
> Then $f$ is an isomorphism.

**Proof**

1. $f$ is injective: Note that any ideal of $R$ is of the form $(0)$ or
   $(\pi^n)$. Thus $\ker(f)$ is either $(0)$ or $(\pi^n)$. But the latter is not possible, since $f(\pi^n)=\varpi^n\neq 0$.
2. $f$ is surjective: Essentially, this is a consequence of Nakayama's Lemma. To be more precise, [Lemma 0315 (1)](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0315) tells us that it suffices to check that $f$ is surjective after quotienting out by $I=(\pi)$. But then condition 2. yields the desired result (noting that everything is already complete in our case).

Comment: My question is that, $f:R→S$ is inclusion and isom, the, R＝S as a set.

Comment: So your answer is helpful, but don't answer my question. Sorry for my poor explanation.